# How do I force Maven to use external repos to retrieve artifacts?

Tags: java, maven, repository, settings, pom.xml

I got following error while trying to build the project. The project is spring project and use IntelliJ with java 8.

```
Could not find artifact org.springframework.data:spring-data-bom:pom:2021.0.0-M2 in nexus (http://maven:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)
```

**Is there a way to fix it through setting.xml?**
I have not access to any configuration on http://maven:8081/nexus/content/groups/public

This is my setting.

```
<settings
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<servers>
    <server>
        <id>releases</id>
        <username>me</username>
        <password>mee</password> <!-- impossible password here :-) -->
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <username>me</username>
        <password>mee</password> <!-- impossible password here :-) -->
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <username>me</username>
        <password>mee</password> <!-- impossible password here :-) -->
    </server>
</servers>

<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://maven:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
        <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central</url>
                <releases><enabled>true</enabled><updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy></releases>
                <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled><updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy></snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central</url>
                <releases><enabled>true</enabled><updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy></releases>
                <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled><updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy></snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>defaultprofile</id>
        <!-- if you want to be able to switch to the defaultprofile profile put this in the active profile -->

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>maven.default</id>
                <name>default maven repository</name>
                <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                <releases><enabled>true</enabled><updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy></releases>
                <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled><updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy></snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>maven.snapshot</id>
                <name>Maven snapshot repository</name>
                <releases><enabled>true</enabled><updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy></releases>
                <url>http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository</url>
                <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled><updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy></snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>vaadin-addons</id>
                <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories> 
    </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Comment: First those entries: `https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central` are simply wrong... Remove them. Second those entries: `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2` are not needed. Remove them as well..If you like to use milestone releases of spring boot you have to add that in your repository manager and not in your pom file because you are already using  a repository manager.

Comment: Please comment on my answer, instead of editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set

```
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    <url>http://maven:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
```

then you send every request to this repository, regardless of the rest of the `settings.xml`. You need to do something like

```
    <mirrorOf>*,!central</mirrorOf>
    <url>http://maven:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
```

but please also correct/remove the URLs as khmarbaise said.

Comment: I did add `<mirror>
            <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*,!central</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://maven:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </mirror>`
and removed the rest, but error still there.

Comment: Did you build with `-U`, so `mvn clean install -U `?

Comment: No, I just do mvn clean install

Comment: Then try again with `-U`, to avoid errors due to caching.